# DevOps, DNS and Public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, elastic-ip

I have a devops automation environment. Each successful build (web app) in Jenkins triggers a creation of EC2 (Linux) instance in AWS which is set to receive public IP and the app gets deployed on that instance. I'm calling the web application using instance's public IP. I need to mask the IP and call the app by custom name. I have created a subdomain on Route 53 subdomain.abc.com. I have three set of web apps and want to call them like one.subdomain.abc.com, two.subdomain.abc.com etc.

Since each time we have a different VM I'm not sure if EIP is an option.
Can someone please suggest a solution ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "we have a different VM"?

Comment: How are you creating the EC2 instance that you deploy to?

Comment: Each time a build takes place another instance is launched. EC2 are being launched using API call.

Comment: I think I have found a workaround. I have to have ELBs and their ALIAS records in Route 53. Each time a new instance is launched it should register itself with the ELB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using just *one* Amazon EC2 instance for each app, then for each app you can:

1. Create an **Elastic IP address** that will be permanently used with the app
2. Create an `A` record in **Amazon Route 53** to point to that Elastic IP address (eg `app1.example.com`)
3. When a new instance of the app is launched, **re-associate the Elastic IP address** with the new instance (assuming your old instance is then terminated)

If you wish to serve traffic from `app1.example.com` to *several* Amazon EC2 instances, then create an `ALIAS` record in Route 53 to point to an **Elastic Load Balancer** and register the EC2 instances with the load balancer.

Comment: I know its not possible to have ELB forwarding requests to two or more different web apps. For example one ELB cannot forward request to app1.example.com and app2.example.com (as far as I know). Just wondering if anyone ever came across any workaround.

Comment: Elastic Load Balancers forward traffic to a collection of EC2 servers. They do *not* forward to a DNS name.